# android object to hashmap (on listview)

Tags: java, android, hashmap

i am trying to listen to click on listview which each row is hashmap:

```
lvItem = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listWork); 
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylistData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
int[] columnID = new int[] {R.id.tvPK, R.id.tvText }; 
map.put("PK", "1"); 
map.put("ITEM", "2"); 
mylistData.add(map);

SimpleAdapter arrayadapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), mylistData, R.layout.row_hidden_id, new String[] {"PK", "ITEM"}, columnID);
lvItem.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
lvItem.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

lvItem.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  
 @Override  
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int p, long id) {   
  Object o = lvItem.getItemAtPosition(p);   
  ErrorMsg("ID:" + o.toString());
 } });
```

i am getting something like "{ITEX=2, PK=1}"
i need to cast the object (o) as hashmap and get only the pk...

any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. The mylistData list is never added to anything (not in the code you've pasted anyways). So you're basically filling the list with some data and then?

Comment: I think you're using an `ArrayAdapter` and filling it with a single `HashMap`. This is probably not what you want. Consider extending `BaseAdapter` and using that to manipulate whatever objects you like.

Comment: edited - forgot 3 lines.. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
lvItem.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  
    @Override  
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int p, long id) {   
        HashMap<String,String> map = (HashMap) lvItem.getItemAtPosition(p);   
        ErrorMsg("ID:" + map.get("PK"));
     } 
});
```